# Statistical significance: Test for different (small) sample sizes?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I recently finished my simulations which I now need to statistically analyse. I am comparing mean firing rates (FR) of neurons in the same population (Pop1) before and after I change the connectivity probability (Pconn).

**I have n=140 observations/simulations for the network with the natural connectivity state, but I have only n=5 observations/simulations for the network with varied connectivity.**

(*I am arbitrarily changing the Pconn, while measuring the FR of a population before and after the change. n=140 observations correspond to BEFORE and n=5 observations correspond to AFTER the change*)

I am quite unsure in which statistical test should I use to determine the significance of my results, since the sizes of samples vary so much. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance, Tea

Comment: Are the observations to be considered independent between the 140 first and 5 second ones? I think that more needs to be clarified about how the tests are done in order to recommend the proper test statistic. Without knowing more about what you have done I would say that a t-test is suited for small sample sizes.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, Jon. I rephrased the question hoping that the dependency between samples is more clearer now!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE, Tea. First of all I'd like to suggest this post gets moved to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as that is the Statistics Stack Exchange and your question is strictly about Statistics.

Now, as a Statistics undergrad, here is my opinion:

Ideally you should get more observations corresponding to AFTER, since you have 140 observations corresponding to BEFORE. If effect, you really have only n = 5 observations because your goal is to compare before vs after and you only have 5 observations related to after. If getting more *after* observations is not possible, then you should use some small-sample significante test, such as the t-test already mentioned. However, notice two things:

1. If you use the t-test, then you should use the paired version of the t-test because your observations correspond to *before* some treatment, and *after* some treatment.
2. The t-test is only appropriate if you assume that your sample data follows some t distribution (or, equivalently, approximately normal). So in order to use a significance t-test you'd first need to test your data to verify it follows a t distribution in the first place. If the latter test fails, you should use a non-parametric (distribution-free) paired test.

Comment: Dear @Victor S., thanks for the suggestions. Since acquiring more observations for the _after_ condition is not possible, I will perform the tests you mentioned!